# Issue with adjustResize value in android

Tags: android

I am using android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" property in manifest and when the keyboard appears the UI goes up too much. Is there any way to change the value of the moving height?

Thanks

Comment: You need to modify your layout accordingly or use adjustPan property. Because using this property, the ui moves up leaving as much space as needed by keypad.

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot yes, adjustPan works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your Issue of layout you can use `adjustPan` property as value of `android:windowSoftInputMode`

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

This will solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here I put my code.which help you lot.

```
        <activity
         android:name=".MainActivity"
         android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait">
       </activity>
```

add android:configChanges and android:windowSoftInputMode mode in every activity where you need to hide keyboard.